# How to unlink files with Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, unlink

I want to replace the file but after I tried the file was not replaced
but here my file is not updated
I would like to delete a file that is found in my localhost.
can anyone help me with it
My controller

```
public function updatesp2d_action() 
{
    $config = array(
    'upload_path'=>'./assets/datasp2d/',
    'allowed_types'=>'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|rar|pdf|',
    'max_size'=>3000
    );

    $this->_rulessp2d();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->update($this->input->post('id_sp2d', TRUE));
    } else {
        $data = array(
    'id_satker' => $this->input->post('id_satker',TRUE),
    'bulan' => $this->input->post('bulan',TRUE),
    'tahun' => $this->input->post('tahun',TRUE),
    'dokumen_pendukung' => $this->input->post('dokumen_pendukung',TRUE),
    'nomial' => $this->input->post('nomial',TRUE),
    ); 

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('dokumen_pendukung'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('file yg anda masukan tidak sesuai'); </script>";
                    $this->updatesp2d();
            }
            else
            {
                if(file_exists($data['dokumen_pendukung']=$path.'./assets/datasp2d/'.$file_name)){
                    unlink($data['dokumen_pendukung']=$path.'./assets/datasp2d/'.$file_name);
                }
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $data['dokumen_pendukung'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
            }
            $this->Sp2d_model->update($this->input->post('id_sp2d', TRUE), $data);
                redirect(site_url('User/sp2d'));

    }
}
```

Comment: where $path and $file_name is defined ?? from where you are getting value for both variables??

Comment: You can use the in build  library method of CI.
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($path);
// unlink also do the same work.
Also, check the file permissions of delete.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right unlink() function is right for it.
You just need to give full path of a file rather than using $path
This is your unlink line of code

```
 unlink($data['dokumen_pendukung']=$path.'./assets/datasp2d/'.$file_name);
```

$path have full URL path which holds HTTP or https which unlink() function don't support.

If your file is in root directory like

```
appliction
system
assets
```

then you provide like this

```
 unlink($data['dokumen_pendukung']='assets/datasp2d/'.$file_name);
```

Comment: it didn't work, still didn't replace the file instead into a double file but thanks for the advice